# How can I reduce the memory footprint of large Random Forest models (sklearn)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, random-forest

I have 100 different Random Forest models. Each of them is in an average 300 MB in size (each trained on over 300 classes). I am using sklearn's (v0.19.1) implementation of Random Forest. This results in over 30 GB memory use. I would need all the models in the memory and have tried reducing the depth of trees but the reduction in accuracy is pretty big. Does anyone have any ideas and/or suggestions(implementations?) that can help me reduce the memory footprint?

Comment: Downvoter, please leave comment so that I can understand what was wrong about the question.

Comment: Why do you have 100 different models? Since an RF is already an ensamble, there is usually not much to gain from ensambling the output even more?

Comment: Have you tried using `min_samples_split` instead of `max_depth` to limit tree growth? This allows different trees to have different depths, which can be beneficial when trying to make the tree more compact.

Comment: Different models because i am dealing with a huge number of classes. So I am splitting training. min_samples_split isn't something I have tried will try and let you know.

Comment: How many classes do you have total? Is the memory usage a problem at training time, or only at inference time?

Comment: How many features do you have?

Comment: How many trees are there in each Random Forest? For some classification problems you can reduce this a lot without loosing much performance, down to maybe 10.

Comment: I have more than 100k classes. Memory usage is a problem at both times but i kind of a hack for the testing. I have 170k features, but the matrix is sparse. There are 10 trees in my forest.

Comment: For 100k classes Random Forest is not really suitable (as you have found). I recommend you open a new question explaining the machine learning task you are trying to solve, so people can recommend more suitable approaches

Comment: I already did that and the only suggestion I got was to try to reduce the number of classes somehow, hierarchically, And that is what I am doing.

Comment: Can you link to the question here?

Comment: Sure: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348064/what-kinds-of-algorithms-work-well-with-hundreds-of-thousands-of-output-classes

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any advanced and elegant solution. But since you use RF, there is always a work-around: you can train 100 DT (or RF) models one after another with different random seeds and store each on disk (erasing it from memory after storing). This way you will have only 300 MB at most in memory at any given time. To make predictions you will need to read models and to predictions one-by-one and to average predicted probabilities. You can generalise this proposal to having N (N=1..5) trees in each of such models to use some modest memory but reduce the number of actual models

Comment: This is exactly my current solution. But I was looking for some way to reduce the size of each of these models without compromising the accuracy. Maybe using a different implementation than sklearn's

Comment: Did you try to understand WHY are your trees so large? How deep are they? Is it due to the large number of classes. In principle, there are RF implementations in  both xgboost and lightgbm, but I have no idea if those are expected to be smaller

Comment: The max_depth is 10 and I tried reducing depth but that kind of reduces the accuracy a lot. It's probably because of the number of classes. I'll try lightbm and xgboost.